# Different length for x and y axis

Tags: r

```
dat=read.csv("r1new.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", dec="."); dat
res.lm = lm(dat$perc~dat$s_perc, data=dat) 
res.res = resid(res.lm)
plot(dat$s_perc, res.lm, 
      ylab="Residuals", 
      xlab="Waiting Time", 
      main="Old Faithful Eruptions",
      type="p") 
abline(0, 0) 
length(dat$res.lm)
length(dat$s_LAI)
```

Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    'x' and 'y' lengths differ

I checked the lenght for the variables which is the same. I just have variables with different lenght, but the ones I am trying to use have the same length, despite the fact that other data after last data point is considered as NA which I don't need.

Comment: res.lm is an object, not a vector. Is res.lm the same that dat$res.lm?  If not, is not the same: plot(dat$s_perc, res.lm,) than plot(dat$s_perc, dat$res.lm)
I think, what you really want is: plot(dat$s_perc, res.res)

Comment: @ArielSC plot(dat$s_perc, res.res) with this function it plots residuals again 2190 values, while actually I have on 37 with respective residuals. In many .csv file, I have several variables with different range (up to 2190).

Comment: @ElvinRufus What about `plot(na.omit(mdat$s_perc), res.res)`?